# alfresco tag still in tagScope after deleting the file

Tags: javascript, tags, alfresco, alfresco-share

I've a problem with the tags in alfresco. Here's the thing:
I create a file and add a tag within a script, then I copy that file in another folder. The tag tree count 2 files for the tag, so far it's ok. If I delete one or both files, the files are gone (obviously) but tags are still on the tree... I've tried to delete it with the tag managing tool in the admin console, I've tried to delete it in a script but nothing works, the tag is still in the tree with no files attached to it. 
Anyone has something for that? I've search and found someone with the same problem but no solution...

Comment: What version of Alfresco are you using? It sounds like a bug - have you considered raising an issue at https://issues.alfresco.com ?

Comment: It's alfresco 5.0 I guess, but I also have the same issue in alfresco community the latest version, I've downloaded it yesterday for testing as I don't have the admin access on the 5.0 version.

Comment: You know the tree tag isn't instantly updated after placing/removing a tag. It takes a while, I'm not sure if it's suppose to be like that. But have you checked that it's probably gone now?

Comment: Still in the tree since about a day and a half, I've been waiting since yesterday morning checking every 30min...

Comment: Have you tried re-indexing? Maybe it was a bad/corrupted node or the index aren't catching up.

Comment: I'm trying to reindex solr with this method: [re-index solr](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/solr-reindex.html) is that what you mean? so far it seems that it still re-indexing since 1 hour (I can't add a tag), I guess it tooks time to achieve this kind of things

Comment: I start over the re-index of solr (successfully this time) and the tags are still in the tree... It's really weird, I've posted an issue at https://issues.alfresco.com and wait for a reply...

Comment: Just a wild guess here, but could it be that your document is still in the recycle bin, and that's what's "holding" the tag there?

Comment: Have you browsed through the node browser to see for the tag? or the node you've deleted

Comment: I've tried that, the recycle bin is empty so no more documents but tags are still here... I also looked at the node browser and the tag root node has no children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally found how to remove these tags. I put the answer here if someone has the same issue, I don't know if this solution is the best (there's probably something more elegant) but it works and after 2 days struggling with this that's all that matters to me :)
So I went to the node browser to find the node corresponding to my site, in the properties there tagScopeCache item that gives a path, I wrote this path and search for the node on the alfresco directory on the hard drive. I found the .bin file rename it in .txt so I was able to open it, inside there is the tag and the count for each of them. I've just delete the two tags which weren't in the site anymore. Then put the extension back to .bin and it works, tags are gone from the tree...

Comment: Sounds like the tag scope cache had got out of date - that shouldn't normally happen. You can force it to be updated by Alfresco using [TaggingService.refreshTagScope](http://dev.alfresco.com/resource/AlfrescoOne/5.0/PublicAPI/org/alfresco/service/cmr/tagging/TaggingService.html#refreshTagScope(org.alfresco.service.cmr.repository.NodeRef,%20boolean)), but only IIRC from Java

Comment: yep that a thing like that, I've tried to refresh the tag scope with javascript but it didn't work nothing change